# Styling Issues w/ IE9. CSS3 Input not recognized

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, styling

Greetings Fellow StackOverflowers, 
I am running into what seems to be a simple issue that I have been unable to debug. All of my CSS (including some CSS3) seems to not display properly when rendered in IE9. Of course, it works great in all other browsers, but IE9 seems to be giving me problems. 
Let me showcase:

Site:
http://www.lmabee.com/test/HDHospital/index.aspx

I have taken what I thought was precautions to avoid the typical IE fails by including the following code fixes in my ASP Master Page:

```
       <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE7.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE8.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
```

I would truly appreciate any hints or tips given. I've been playing with this IE thing for 12 hours now and feel I am hitting burn out. 
Best regards,
Laura

Comment: Screenshots are not enough to help you. Need code or URL.

Comment: Sorry. CSS code is:
http://www.lmabee.com/css-site.txt

Comment: CSS code is nice, but it wont work without HTML. =) Just show the complete site.

Comment: Thanks Radio. :)
I've added the site link:
http://www.lmabee.com/test/HDHospital/index.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS you are using linear-gradient, which is not supported in IE below version 10.
For IE 9 and below, you need to add:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#002c3e', endColorstr='#000a10');
```

This one is for #container_header {}

Comment: Thank you so much Radio. You're amazing. Using your help with the container_header I was able to fix everything but the footer, and I think that's a separate issue all together. I truly appreciate your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just want to add another comment that your help solved all my problems, including the footer. Thanks so much Radio. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. As long as you stay cross-browsered with gradients - things should work well.